# How can i connect my spring boot application to kafka topic as soon as it restarts

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

How can I connect my Springboot application to Kafka topic as soon as the application start,
so that when send method is invoked there is no need to fetch the metadata information?

Comment: Can you please share any code you've tried so far that you're having issues with?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka clients are required to do an initial metadata fetch to determine the leader broker to actually send the data, but this shouldn't drastically change the startup time of any application and wouldn't prevent you from calling any Kafka producer actions

Comment: connected through smartlifecycle  and fetched the metadata from producer.partitionfor 
 still first messge is taking more time to be sent to the topic.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but you shouldn't be able to bypass the actual producer protocol by doing similar actions manually